# why copy with drag and drop not working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I updated my vscode and they mentioned the point on their release notes for March 2017.

```
Copy with drag and drop - Choose whether to copy or cut when you drag and drop in the editor.
```

Why my vscode doesn't copy or cut when drag and drop the selected text. Should i need to install any extension for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `"editor.dragAndDrop":true` in your `settings.json`

Comment: The description on `Editor: Drag and Drop` says "Controls whether the editor should allow moving selections via drag and drop", but I don't think that applies here. Maybe you mean `Explorer: Enable Drag and Drop`? But that one says "Controls whether the explorer should allow to move files and folders via drag and drop. This setting only effects drag and drop from inside the explorer." Both of those settings are on for me, but I still can't drag and drop from outside VSCode to inside VSCode

Comment: In newer versions of VS Code, you may have to also update `"explorer.enableDragAndDrop": true`.

Answer (score 5):

I am using `Windows 10`, I also met the same issue.

Because there are two kinds of installers for Visual Studio Code: `User Installer` and `System Installer`, the `User Installer` have less privilege, but the `User Installer` is put in the first place in the [official download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/#alt-downloads).

[image: vs code-download option]

If you are an administrator account, any one of these two installers is OK.

But if you are non-administrator account and you installed the `User Installer`, the issue "drag and drop not working" will come.

So the solution is uninstall the `User Installer` of VS code, then re-install `System Installer` of VS code. It works perfect for me, may it be helpful for you too.

#### Current installation path by installer:

- `System Installer`

  - `%ProgramFiles%`\Microsoft VS Code
- `User Installer`

  - `%LocalAppData%`\Programs\Microsoft VS Code

Comment: Was really hopeful this would solve it for me, but no luck, at least with VSCode insiders

Comment: The same problem occurred when installed with `System Installer`, but was solved by installing with `User Installer`

Answer (score 2):

it's an known issue, please refer to :
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/93599

btw, you could use "Download" from right click menu

Comment: This one is specific to Remote VSCode windows, but I can't drag-and-drop to or from even a local VSCode window on Windows 10

Comment: The right click download is a great workaround! When I drag and drop from local to explorer it uploads, but when I drag and drop from explorer to local it creates a file with the path (not the actual path). Not sure what the issue is...

Answer (score 1):

Release notes also say -

```
On macOS, press and hold the Option key while you drag and drop. Press the Ctrl key on Windows and press the Alt key on Linux.
```

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_drag-and-drop-improvements)

Comment: I also tried it by holding ctrl key, but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Select some text, press ctrl key, hover cursor on the selection and drag